# SQL - Joining two tables with some different and some same columns

Tags: sql

I have two tables, which look like this:

**TABLE A**

```
-------
AGENCY_ID | ISSUE_YEAR | AMOUNT_ISSUED
00101     | 1996       | 3000
00123     | 1996       | 4000
00165     | 1996       | 3450
00231     | 1996       | 6000
```

**TABLE B**

```
-------
AGENCY_ID | ISSUE_YEAR | AMOUNT_EXPIRED
00101     | 1996       | 4000
00101     | 1997       | 2550
00123     | 1996       | 1250
00123     | 1997       | 1300
00165     | 1996       | 3333
00165     | 1997       | 3124
00231     | 1996       | 1232
00231     | 1997       | 2422
```

Which should be joined together, merging the shared columns and fill the missing values as 0, like this:

**TABLE JOINED_A_B**

```
-------
AGENCY_ID | ISSUE_YEAR | AMOUNT_EXPIRED | AMOUNT_ISSUED   
00101     | 1996       | 4000           | 3000
00101     | 1997       | 2550           | 0
00123     | 1996       | 1250           | 4000
00123     | 1997       | 1300           | 0
00165     | 1996       | 3333           | 3450
00165     | 1997       | 3124           | 0
00231     | 1996       | 1232           | 6000
00231     | 1997       | 2422           | 0
```

I have attempted to use `UNION` to join them, but the dimension of my result table is always the same as the one on the left side of the `UNION` operator (`SELECT A UNION SELECT B` results in a table without column `AMOUNT_EXPIRED`).

How should I do this correctly? Maybe Union is not a good choice?

Thanks!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want `left join` and `coalesce()`:

```
select b.*, coalesce(a.amount_issued, 0) as amount_issued
from b left join
     a
     on b.agency_id = a.agency_id and b.issue_year = a.issue_year;
```